# Replace all consecutive single quote pairs with double quotes

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp

I am trying replace all consecutive single quote pairs with double quotes.

Code:

```
text.replace('\'\'','\"')
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Background:
I am extracting article text from stored .html files using Goose.

```
article = extractor.extract(raw_html=html)              #extracts content
text = (unidecode(article.cleaned_text))                  #changes encoding
```

Here article is in unicode and text in str. I am using Python 2.
I try to print the text.

`print text`

Output:

```
''Several people were crushed or trampled to death,'' the police said in a statement.
```

instead of

```
\'\'Several people were crushed or trampled to death,\'\' the police said in a statement.
```

This is somewhat confusing to me. My code would work if it was in the second format. I don't understand how the string is stored even given the quotes are not preceeded by `\`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `text.replace("''",'"')`

This works because the double quoted string didn't need to be escaped.

Comment: he want to replace consecutive `'` not all single `'`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to replace each single quote with double quotes. I want to replace consecutive pair with double.

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia add an example along with expected output.